# Dynamic optimisation / optimal control where control is a function of state

Tags: functional-analysis, optimal-control, dynamic-programming, hamilton-equations

I am familiar with the usual optimal control problem of the form:
$$
\min_{u(t)}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}{f(t,x(t),u(t))}dt\\
\text{s.t.}~\dot{x}(t)=g(t,x(t),u(t))\\
\text{given } x(0), t_0, t_1.
$$
I am currently modeling a problem, where my *control* is a *function* of my *state* variable, and the state, in turn, depends on the control and its derivative:

$$
\min_{u(t)}\int_{t_0}^{t_1}{f(t,x(t, u(x), u'(x)),u(x))}dt\\
\text{s.t.}~u'(x)\geq 0\\
\text{given } x(0), t_0, t_1.
$$

I do have an equation for $x(t,u(x))$, but $u(x)$ is free and to be determined, so this is not a closed form. I wonder if there is a way to reduce this problem (possibly redefining the state variable) to make it tractable in a usual Hamiltonian, or if I need to go to the theory of infinite dimensional controls (because $u$ is a function of $x$ and only indirectly of $t$).

Answer (score 2):

If the control is subject to dynamics then it can be treated as a state. Simply include a brand new control, for instance $v(t)$, and write the new dynamics as:

$$
\dot{x}_a =
\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{x} \\
\dot{u}
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
f(x, u, t) \\
v
\end{bmatrix} =
f_a(x_a, v, t)
$$
with $v \geq 0$.

For $u$ to be a function of $x$ is a matter of including a path constraint of the form:
$$
g_a(x_a,t) = u - g(x,t) = 0
$$
Similarly, if $x$ is a function of $u$ the path constraint is:
$$
g_a(x_a,t) = x - g(u,t) = 0
$$

if $u$ is a function of $x$ then $x$ cannot be a function of $u$! If this is the case, and the constraints are linearly independent, then the problem is infeasible, as no solutions can satisfy the two constraints simultaneously.

Finally, if $x$ is not subject to dynamics, then $x$ is not a state! In this case simply switch the names of the variables in your second problem statement.